# How to separate admin side from public side on one Rails application with one database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, admin, single-page-application

I am developing Rails Application and I am thinking ways how to separate admin side from public side. System has users that have their own roles. Depending on their roles users will be redirected either to public side or to admin side. Nobody can access the application without authentication. Admin side is a standard multipage application and public side is a one page application that uses api. Could you anyone please suggest to me how to create this kinda architecture in one Rails application with one database.

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of authorization libraries exist for rails apps.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authorization